# Low-level streaming multimedia: A new API based on Khronos OpenMAX AL 1.0.1

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-ndk

I have seen that Android has enabled OpenMAX API in NDK r7.

http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/11/updated-ndk-for-android-40.html

Can any one tell me what Low level streaming is and how this could be used.
I don't have any idea about it. Can it be used to decode video from my sd card and play them.
Does it help play HD.

Answer (score 3):

Download NDK r7, then read android-ndk-r7\docs\openmaxal\index.html.
In addition, there is an example at: android-ndk-r7\samples\native-media\